# how to change extended attributes on mac recovery

Tags: terminal, mac, bash, recovery, python

xattr worked on mac desktop system

but I want to let it work in mac recovery terminal

but xattr is not included in bash of terminal

I copy xattr   to usb drive and run it on recovery terminal ,but it not working and tip :

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/2.7/Resources/Python.app: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

How to solve this problem?
Thank you !

Comment: Why do you want to run it? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to change file's extended attributes on recovery

Comment: Which files? The current macOS really ties things down and I can't think of reasons to try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: This answer was also tested using High Sierra.

The macOS Recovery for newer versions of macOS do include the `xattr` command. Going back to Mavericks, I find that the `xattr` command is not included in OS X Recovery. However, if while booted to OS X Recovery for Mavericks, you have a working Mavericks installed, then you still can use the `xattr` command that was included with Mavericks. The image below was taken while booted to OS X Recovery for Mavericks. This image shows Mavericks is installed on the `Macintosh HD` volume.

[image: starutp disk]

The commands below were entered in a Terminal window while booted to OS X Recovery for Mavericks.

Below is the output from the `echo $PATH` command.

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Below is the output from the `ls /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/usr/bin/xattr` command.

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/usr/bin/xattr
```

So the `xattr` command would be in the search path for commands, if the colon‑separated list of directories output by `echo $PATH` were proceeded with `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD`. As the OP has pointed out, other software (such as python) may need to be included in this path. This can be accomplished by proceeding the `xattr` command with the `chroot` command, as shown below.

```
chroot "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" xattr
```

In this case the `chroot` command changes its root directory to the supplied directory `"/Volumes/Macintosh HD"`.

### Example When Accessing a File in the Current Working Directory

If the current working directory contained the file `test.txt`, then the following command would **not** work. (Unless the current working directory was `/Volumes/Macintosh HD`.)

```
chroot "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" xattr -c test.txt
```

However, the following command would cause all attributes to be removed from the file `test.txt`.

```
chroot "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" xattr -c "$PWD/test.txt"
```

Using `$PWD` works in the above command, because `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD` is a symbolic link to `/`.

### How to Remount When Necessary to Access One or More Files

> Note: Any remounting only persists until the Mac restarts.

If one or more files to be accessed do not reside in the Mavericks startup volume, then the mount point for each of these other volumes will need to be moved to the Mavericks startup volume. For example, if the `test.txt` file is stored in the `MyHFS` volume instead of in the `Macintosh HD` volume, then you will need to remount the `MyHFS` volume. First, enter the command below to unmount the `MyHFS` volume.

```
diskutil unmount MyHFS
```

Example output is shown below.

```
Volume MyHFS on disk1s3 unmounted
```

Next, use the commands below to insure the new mount point exists in the `Macintosh HD` volume, then mount the `MyHFS` volume at that point. The identifier `disk1s3` that is entered should be the same as shown in the above output.

```
mkdir -p /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Volumes/MyHFS
diskutil mount -mountpoint /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Volumes/MyHFS disk1s3
```

Example output is shown below.

```
Volume MyHFS on disk1s3 mounted
```

Comment: Thank you.  I repect your work.But       chroot "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" xattr -c "$PWD/test.txt"   also not working , it can not find the test.txt which I put in the current dir. But chroot "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" xattr -h        can list the help .

Comment: What is the value of the `PWD` variable?

Comment: My usb name is AAA,   first I cd /Volumes/AAA, my test.txt file path is /Volumes/AAA/test.txt, $PWD variable is /Volumes/AAA, but no matter:  chroot "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" xattr -c "$PWD/test.txt"    or   chroot "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" xattr -c /Volumes/AAA/test.txt      not  working,both of then say no that file

Comment: I made the assumption you would be only accessing files stored on the Mavericks startup volume. Since I now know you may access files on other volumes, I added the section *"How to Remount When Necessary to Access One or More Files"*.

Comment: Great! I repect that,and  It worked by the section.But unfortunately the usb volume is my app located and I can not move it. So I make a soft link on the /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/mac/Desktop/1.sh ,which link to /Volumes/AAA/test.txt , and I confirm the soft link is correct .But again,cannot find the file. I think the path in softlink is not worked after chroot,so Is there a good way to achieve the target ? Thank you !

Comment: I did not ask you to move any files. I stated to remount the `AAA` volume to where the volume would be mounted if you were to boot to OS X (macOS). You can remount the `AAA` volume back to the original mount point after using the `xattr` command. The `chroot` command moves the root directory from `/` to `/Volumes/Macintosh HD`. At this point you can not access any directories or files that are outside of `/Volumes/Macintosh HD`. Adding a soft link that goes outside of `/Volumes/Macintosh HD` can not work. The mount point `/Volumes/AAA` is outside of `/Volumes/Macintosh HD`.

Answer (score 0):

The xattr command has relied on the system-bundled python2. If you've copied the command for use in the recovery partition, it won't work, as the Recover Partition doesn't have python.